# How to provide centering and relative layout at same time

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is the layout I am trying to achieve.  So I know how to center and left right justify, but when I combine with RelativeLayout I am not getting desired result.  The TextViews all go left unless margin/padding is added.  I have the right formula for Left-Right-Center but when I want to put some text next to these it does not work.

```
 <ImageView> <TextView>   <ImageView><TextView>     <ImageView><TextView>
```

Here is my layout (it only includes one text which needed lots of margin because it was way over to the left:

```
  <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/reply_button" android:src="@drawable/icons_reply"
        android:layout_width="60dp" andorid_layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Reply"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/reply_button" android:layout_marginLeft="50dip" android:textSize="12sp"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/resend_button" android:src="@drawable/icons_resend"
        android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/select_button"  android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:focusable="false" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:src="@drawable/select_icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `ImageView` to the left of each `TextView`, simply set a left coumpound drawable to the left of your `TextView` and place them in a `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <TextView
    ...
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourimage"
    android:drawablePadding="3dp" //optional, if you want some padding
    android:gravity="center_vertical" // to center vertically the text and drawable
    weight="1" // use this in a LinearLayout so they will be 
               // uniformly distributed over the space
    ...
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can set the whole TextView clickable. Other solution work as well, they'll just consume more resources

Answer (score 0):

You should nest these in other Relative layouts and put them in one big linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout.....>

<RelativeLayout
android:weight=1>
<image>
<Text>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:weight=1
>
<image>
<Text>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:weight=1>
<image>
<Text>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```